# Pass a mysql link to a function

Tags: php, mysqli

Here's the function:

```
function getCount($module, $db_link) {
    if($module == "tweets") {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweets WHERE `read`='n'";
        $tweet_count = mysqli_query($db_link,$query);
        echo $tweet_count;
    }
}
```

Here's the link (which is defined earlier in the code):

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "twitterd", "password", "twitterd") or die('Cannot connect to the database');
```

The function call:

```
<?php getCount("tweets", $mysqli); ?>
```

How do I pass the `$mysqli` link to the getCount function?  Currently, I get this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in lib.php on line 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is being passed just fine; the problem is this:

```
echo $tweet_count;
```

You can't convert a MySQL resource to a string. Fetch the row:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($tweet_count);
echo $row[0];
```